# Using SqlFunctions or Equivalent Collection of EdmFunctions with MySql and Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using Linq to Entities, backed by MySql. I'd like to be able to use various built in MySql functions such as `rand`. If I were using MS SQL Server I could use the SqlFunctions class, but this does not work with MySql; I get the error:

> Rand() on the type 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' cannot
>   be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.

I've figured out how the create a user defined function on my database that wraps the built in RAND:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Random ()
RETURNS real NOT DETERMINISTIC
RETURN RAND();
```

I then update my model from the database (I'm using an .ebmx), and create a static class like so:

```
public static class MyUserFunctions {
    [EdmFunction("MyModelNamespace.Store", "Random")]
    public static double Random() {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}
```

And that allows me to call MyUserFunctions.Random within a .Where clause over my Entities class:

```
using (MyEntities entities = new MyEntities()) {
    // Yes, I know ORDER BY RAND() is slow
    return entities.products.OrderBy(prod => MyUserFunctions.Random()).Take(4);
}
```

So the question is, can I do this without creating the stupid wrapper UDF, and just make all the built in MySql functions available more directly (perhaps by setting the `EdmFunction`'s `Namespace` property properly (in the case of `SqlFunctions` the namespace is `"SqlServer"`).

Comment: have you added the MySQL .NEt Connector to your project? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Answer (score 0):

there are some `Canonical Functions` that all the provider must be support those, see this: [Canonical Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but i guess there is no `Random` canonical function, if there is `Random` on the list, you can simply create `CLR Method` and map it to `Random` by `EdmFunction` attribute and `Edm` `NamespaceName`, and there is no need to create a `UDF` and `<function> element` in your model... , if there is not any `Random` canonical function, you can create a `function` element in conceptual schema definition language (CSDL) containing a `DefiningExpression` element, and write your statement (in TSQL probably) in this section, instead of defining `UDF` in `DataBase`, and defining `input parameter` and `return type` for it, and map a `CRL function` by `EdmFunction` to it, and call from `linq` query, see this: [Call Model-Defined Functions in Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)